# How to use a JS library in Typescript without a Definition file (React-Summernote)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, summernote

I want to use React-Summernote but its typings are not available
I tried doing the following

```
let ReactSummernote1: any = require('react-summernote');
let ReactSummernote = ReactSummernote1.ReactSummernote;
```

..

```
 <ReactSummernote
     value={this.props.content}
     options={{
                   dialogsInBody: true,
                   toolbar: [
                      ['style', ['style']],
                      ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                      ['fontname', ['fontname', 'fontsize', 'color']],
                      ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                      ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'table', 'hr']],
                      ['view', ['codeview']]
                   ]
                 }}
   onChange={!this.props.scheduledSession ? this.props.contentUpdated : function () { } } />
```

but this give an error

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you are having problems with finding path to a file. You can change your server config-file. I am using webpack. Here is copy of my webpack-config.js. You can change lines you don't need.

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool:"eval",
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
    './src/index.tsx'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react')
    },
    extensions:[".js", ".ts", ".tsx","", ".webpack.js", ".web.js"],
    fallback: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    root: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'ts'],
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
        loaders: [
            'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

After that this should work.

```
const ReactSummernote = require('react-summernote');
```

or you can try useing `./` to navigate

**Note:** Be sure you are redirecting to the right folder.

```
const Name = require ('./../folder/file-name');
```

Comment: const ReactSummernote = require ('./../folder/file-name');

this gives an error  "JSX element type 'ReactSummernote' does not have any construct or call signatures

Comment: well if you want to use that then you need to change `folder/file-name` to the real-path of `react-summernote` on your pc

Comment: did that only 
const ReactSummernote = require('../../../node_modules/react-summernote/dist/react-summernote')

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a custom type definition file (custom_name.d.ts)

```
declare module 'react-summernote' {
    var _reactSummernote: any;
    export = _reactSummernote;
}
```

Then you can import the module using the standard syntax

```
import * as ReactSummernote from 'react-summernote';
```

For more info:
http://definitelytyped.org/guides/best-practices.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42547859/typescript-how-to-write-definition-file-for-react-jsx

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Vnkitaev/react-summernote/blob/master/src/Summernote.jsx#L111), the library `react-summernote`  does a default export of `ReactSummernote`

so using node require, you should be able to do

```
const ReactSummernote = require('react-summernote');
```

To use it in JSX, you will likely need at minimum to type it as a ReactComponent:

```
const ReactSummernote = require('react-summernote') as React.ComponentClass<any>;
```

Coming up with Type Definitions and contributing them to DefinitelyTyped would be a great move...

Comment: Tried with react component
getting the same error "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. "

Comment: previously doing

import { somthing } from "xyz" solved the same problem bt this requires type definitions