# How to write Definition File for React JSX

Tags: typescript, reactjs, summernote, definitelytyped

I want to write a custom definition file for Summernote.jsx so that i dont get react-summernote module not found

i have written

```
declare var ReactSummernote: JSX.ElementClass;

declare module "react-summernote" {

    export default ReactSummernote;
}
```

and imported this as

```
import ReactSummernote from 'react-summernote';
```

but got an error saying

```
"JSX element type 'ReactSummernote' does not have any construct or call signatures"
on
<ReactSummernote />
```

following is the link

[Summernote.JSX](https://github.com/Vnkitaev/react-summernote/blob/master/src/Summernote.jsx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just declare the module as:

`declare module "react-summernote";`

Or more specifically:

```
declare module "react-summernote" {
    import * as React from "react";
    let ReactSummernote: React.ComponentClass<any>;
    export default ReactSummernote;
}
```